# WordPress Woocommerce : show recent products, in a randomized order

Tags: php, wordpress, random, woocommerce

I would like to display X recent products, randomly sorted, using a Woocommerce shortcode or a PHP function.

This shortcode...

```
[recent_products per_page="16" columns="4" orderby="rand"]
```

...displays 16 random products from the entire catalog (not the 16 last products randomly sorted).

Even if my Woocommerce settings specify that the default sorting is random, using this shortcode...

```
[recent_products per_page="16" columns="4"]
```

...displays the last 16 products ordered by date.

Answer (score 0):

[**Recent Products**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6)

```
[recent_products per_page="16" columns="16" orderby="rand" order="ASC"]
```

I am not sure but could you please try this code?

Comment: It doesn't work. "rand" is not a valid value for the "order" attribute.